# How do I disable the slash and apostrophe keys from popping up quick find in Firefox with html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I'm making a game with HTML that uses a lot of the keys on the keyboard.  I have event handlers set up for `$(document).keypress`, but when I press the <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd> keys in Firefox, "quick find" appears, interrupting the game and shifting the focus away from the document.

How can I disable this?  I don't have the problem in Chrome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass Quick Search Firefox feature and capture forward slash keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797937/how-to-bypass-quick-search-firefox-feature-and-capture-forward-slash-keypress)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using jquery, there is the method "preventDefault()" in the Event object. It's a good solution due to it's compatibility in all major browsers.

```
$('selector').bind('event', function (event){
  event.preventDefault(); //this is what you want.
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 9):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
Just call this in your key listener, when ' or / is pressed.

Comment: Since this page has disappeared, the solution is to add `event.preventDefault();` to your event-handling function.