# How do I stop websites from breaking searchkey ("/") in Firefox UI?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

This question is the counterpoint to another question:

[How to bypass Quick Search Firefox feature and capture forward slash keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797937/how-to-bypass-quick-search-firefox-feature-and-capture-forward-slash-keypress)

Firefox supports using `/` as a search hotkey. (Internally, this appears to be `cmd_findTypeText`.) It is the most usable implementation of in-page searching/navigation that I've ever seen - I probably use it a hundred times a day. However, in recent years, a number of webapps have specifically overloaded/broken/replaced this feature with their own inferior, adhoc search UIs (e.g. google.com and most sites running Atlassian Confluence). For people who use this feature in Firefox, it interrupts the "flow" of web-browsing.

It appears that one might be able to patch Firefox to assign a different key (e.g. modify `platformHTMLBindings.xml` in `toolkit.jar` to specify "<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>" or <kbd>[</kbd>) -- but that solution would not be maintainable during Firefox's frequent upgrades.

Note: Some alternative search-related hotkeys are available (such as "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>" / "<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>", <kbd>,</kbd>, or "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>" / "<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>"), but these provide different functionality.

How can one (maintainably) stop websites from overloading "/" (`cmd_findTypeText`)? Alternatively, how can one (maintainably) assign it to a different key?

Comment: For what its worth, `Ctrl-F` seems to always work

Comment: Yes, Ctrl-F helps and works consistently -- it's a fallback but not as good. Both Ctrl-F and "/" highlight matching text -- but they differ when matching on hypertext. With "/", you can click the hypertext in a quarter-second (by pressing enter). With Ctrl-F, it's more like 2-4 seconds (move hand to mouse/trackpad; then adjust pointer; then click).

Comment: @user2114266 `Ctrl-F` can be used to click links. Find link text then `ESC` `ENTER`.

Comment: @diolemo Thanks, just added this comment in that fashion!