# Disable slash and apostrophe from opening quick find on firefox

Tags: firefox

Firefox's quick find feature is very annoying. Can you please help me to disable quick find. When I press slash or apostrophe, firefox brings up quick find, which is hindering my work. Please help.

thanks and regards,
Durga Prasad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass Quick Search Firefox feature and capture forward slash keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797937/how-to-bypass-quick-search-firefox-feature-and-capture-forward-slash-keypress)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can disable it (or alternatively, remap it), using an extension, the **SearchHotkeys**: https://freeshell.de//~kaosmos/index-en.html#searchkeys

mozillaZine has this information as well: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Find_bar_opens_when_typing_in_textbox

Answer (score 12):

Good news: as of Firefox 63 there is finally a feature to disable this!

Go to `about:config`

Find `accessibility.typeaheadfind.manual` and set it to false.

Found the info here: https://techdows.com/2018/06/disable-quick-find-firefox.html

Actual bug thread tracking this issue: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418033

Comment: Thanks! Installing an extension that needed a lot of permissions, to do this seemed dubious

Answer (score 3):

2016: searchhotkeys no longer maintained after firefox switched to xpi extensions. Disabling addon signing to install it (about:config , xpinstall.signatures.required : false) still doesn't mean it works. Not an answer, but hopefully will save people following signs towards dead ends.

I also searched for "search" in about:config and came up short.

edit: now solved, see this thread for workaround: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=942269

Comment: what is the workaround in that thread? i tried this dorando  plugin, disabled '/', but still get quick find activated.

Comment: see my steps in last comment. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The [Shortkeys add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys) disables the Firefox Finder shortcuts (' and /). It seems to just assign apostrophe (') and forward slash (/) to a function that does nothing.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys

This is the add-on dez93_2000 mentioned.