# How can I prevent Firefox from opening its "find in page" bar?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, dom-events

I'm developing a game which needs to accept keyboard input anywhere over an HTML div (so, not in a conventional HTML text/area input).

I've added a key press handler to a DOM element, which is seeing the key events, but whenever I press a key, Firefox (58.0.2 currently) also opens a "find in page" bar at the bottom of the window. (It's similar to the one which opens if you do CMD-F, but without the Highlight All, Match Case, Whole Words options; but it does have results eg "2 of 2 matches"). If I don't type anything for a few seconds, it goes away again - but if I type a second character, it has grabbed the focus and my key press handler never sees any further events.

Is there a way of programmatically disabling this feature? I've tried setting the event not to propagate (and also key up/down events!), but it had no effect on this.

(This feature can be turned off by the user, by opening Preferences and unchecking "Search for text when I start typing", but I really don't want to have to write a series of tutorial screens guiding users through doing this themselves before they can play the game.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bypass Quick Search Firefox feature and capture forward slash keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797937/how-to-bypass-quick-search-firefox-feature-and-capture-forward-slash-keypress)

Comment: If the search is popping up for any key press you probably have the "Search for text when you start typing" option enabled; the solution given for the linked question can be used for that case as well.

Comment: "Search for text when you start typing" isn't quite identical to Quick Search - I guess it's actually the successor to it - but you're right, event.preventDefault() is still the solution. Thanks!